# How to define order of fields in CRD

Tags: kubernetes

I have a CRD which contains several fields. like:

```
            properties:
                fieldA:
                    type: boolean
                fieldB:
                    type: string
                    nullable: false
                fieldC:
                    type: integer
                fieldD:
                    type: string
                    nullable: false
```

Whenever I create a CR from it

```
fieldA: true
fieldB: "blabla"
fieldC: 23
fieldD: "blabla2"
```

then run `kubectl get myCR -o yaml`, the field order seems random:

```
fieldD: "blabla2"
fieldB: "blabla"
fieldC: 23
fieldA: true
```

Is there a way to keep the order defined either in CRD or CR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The fields are part of a key-value-map. And a map stores no information about the order.
You can change it to a list (which ensure the correct order), but this will make things really hard (for you and users of your CRD).